# Encrypt or hide user's API key used in program python 3

Tags: python, api, security, cryptography

I'm finalizing a desktop Python3/Tkinter application where I ask to the user his API key.
Then, he can use a simplified form to search content in the API and obtain results list.
**His API key is used by the code in order to send requests but I don't keep it in any file**

At this time, the user's API key is stored in plaintext inside a variable.

**What is the proper way to store and secure this key in this situation?**

I read some articles about encryption/decryption but I'm not able to adapt it to my case.

Comment: The API should be in some configuration file that is not part of the program.  The location of the configuration file is an argument to the program.

Comment: The APi we are talking about is a public one. It is not mine.

Comment: I should have written "API key".  The user's key should be in a file and read by your program, not actually be in the program.

Comment: This configuration should be hidden in this case. And I don't know how because in any cases, my program should access the key in order to send requests to the API.

Comment: I don't think this is possible by the time you need your key in plaintext form to send requests to the API, except if API supports an encryption system and make an E2E encryption, so you send the key encrypted and the API's server decrypts it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can save the key in an environment variable.

You can do it like that:

```py
import os
os.environ["DEBUSSY"] = "1"
```

2. You can create a configuration file for every client.

You don't have to encrypt anything in this case. It will work like a cookie variable in web. So just make a file in user home/your configuration directory and save it there.

```py
with open(".myapp", "w") as f:
    f.write(api_key)
```

Now you can just check if the file/key exists on the client side and load the key if it is.